# I try to download one poster to each movie, but every poster is downloaded multiple times. Is something wrong with my loop or rendering context?

Tags: python, django, download, django-templates

Models.py

```
class Movie(models.Model):

    movie_title = models.CharField(max_length=150, primary_key=True)
    movie_plot = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    poster_image = models.FileField(upload_to='posters', null=True, blank=True)
    movie_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    movie_genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    movie_director = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    imdb_link = models.URLField()
    movie_year = models.IntegerField()
```

Views.py

```
def movielist(request):

movies = ['Batman.Begins.2005.720p.BRrip.x264.YIFY', 'Dark knight rises', 'the+shawshank+redemption', 'the green mile', 'the dark knight']
movie_class_list = []

for movie in movies:
    if 'year' in guessit.guess_movie_info(movie):
        movie_name = guessit.guess_movie_info(movie)['title']
        movie_year = guessit.guess_movie_info(movie)['year']
        url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+movie_name+"&y="+str(movie_year)


    else:
        movie_name = guessit.guess_movie_info(movie)['title']
        url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+movie_name


    data = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))



    if data['Response'] == 'True':
        movie_title = data['Title']
        movie_plot = data['Plot']
        poster_image = data['Poster']
        movie_score = data['imdbRating']
        movie_genre = data['Genre']
        movie_director = data['Director']
        imdb_link = "http//imdb.com/title/" + data['imdbID']
        movie_year = data['Year']
        movie_class = Movie(movie_title, movie_plot, poster_image, movie_score, movie_genre, movie_director,
                            imdb_link, movie_year=movie_year)

        movie_class.save(poster_image)
        movie_class_list.append(movie_class)


template = loader.get_template('movieapp/movielist.html')
context = RequestContext(request, {
    'movie_class_list' : movie_class_list,
})
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

This is how my code looks. I want to download poster images from URL provided by API but every time I run server it downloads posters multiple times. For example right now, with 5 movies on my list, every poster is downloaded 6 times, with 3 movies on list 4 times, and with one movie one poster is downloaded twice. The line "movie_class.save(poster_image)" runs this function http://ishcray.com/downloading-and-saving-image-to-imagefield-in-django but I didn't put this in my code here since I've tried many other saving functions from stackoverflow and everything works as I mentioned above so this is right I guess.

My theories: 
1) Something is wrong with my loop
2) last 4 lines from my code execute this function multiple times.

Could you help me find a mistake here and explain why doesn't it work? I couldn't find anything in documentation.

edit: my template

```
{% if movie_class_list %}

    {% for movie in movie_class_list %}
        <li>     

          <img src="{{movie.poster_image}}" width="220" height="342">

          <p>{{movie.movie_score}} / 10
          <p>{{movie.movie_title}} ({{movie.movie_year}})</p>
          <p>{{movie.movie_director}}</p>
          <p>{{movie.movie_plot}}</p>
          <p>{{movie.movie_genre}}</p>
        </li>


    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>no movies</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Have you tried with only one movie in the list? Does rendering the template include any loops?

Comment: I tried with one movie and one poster was downloaded twice.

Comment: And what about the template? If you print movie_class_list immediately before the render does it have the repeated poster references?

Comment: Added template code to the main post. But I doubt it can change anything since even one movie doesn't works properly. I check print in a moment.

Comment: Are you still calling the save function? At a quick glance that appears to do a download.

Comment: I added print statement just behind save function and it gets printed 30 times with 5 movies on my list. So yes, I'm still calling it. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Keep adding some more print statements - e.g. at the start of the movielist function to see how many times it is called. You could add an __init__ method to the Movie class and print whenever it is called (i.e. as an instance is created) to see when instances are created, and how many, ...

Comment: added print at start of movielist function, it gets called 6 times with 5 movies on list. When I deleted four last lines and leave it with just `return HttpResponse('test')` it downloaded single posters as it should. So the mistake must be made somewhere in rendering context, but I still can't see how.

Comment: Keep adding those prints - you'll find it in the end.